# Difference between a = a || b and a ||= b

Tags: ruby

I am reading through Programming Ruby, The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide (The Pick Axe Book), and the author claims that there's a difference between:

```
var = var || "Default Value"
```

and:

```
var || = "Default Value"
```

I don't understand this, as there is no difference from what I can see. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: As far as I know, the two expressions will have the same result for any value of `var`? Can you please add a quote from the book to your question, to give an indication of what the author means? :-)

Comment: I think its just two ways of writing the same expression.

Comment: You guys are cool. Thanks

Comment: It has to be `||=`, not `|| =` (the latter raises a syntax error)

Comment: Why is it so? It's just white space right.

Comment: @gates Ruby's parser doesn't allow it. It's like `i += 1` (ok) vs `i + = 1` (syntax error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the resource [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html):

> In a = a || b, a is set to something by the statement on every run,
>   whereas with a || a = b, a is only set if a is logically false (i.e.
>   if it's nil or false) because || is 'short circuiting'. That is, if
>   the left hand side of the || comparison is true, there's no need to
>   check the right hand side.

This basically means they'll behave similarly to you, the dev, but internally the implementations differ as explained above.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments, the above explanation considers `a || a = b` instead of `a ||= b`. A very good point, and reading the same link further clarifies this:

> If a is not defined, a || a = 42 raises NameError, while a ||= 42
>   returns 42. So, they don't seem to be equivalent expressions.

So, again, they're not the same statement, because Ruby allocates a variable the moment it sees an assignment at parse-time (which is the case for `a ||= 42`).

One final quote so you don't think I'm making this up, :)

> Ruby sees the assignment at the parsing stage and creates the variable
>   in a way that it wouldn't with a || a = 42, even though it ends up
>   behaving like the latter once actual execution occurs.

Comment: Is this what OP is referring to though? The question states difference between `a = a || b` and `a ||= b`, not `a = a || b` and `a || a = b`?

Comment: @Drenmi: `a ||= b` is a shortcut for  `a || a = b`. (_i.e. assignment is skipped in case `a` is not `nil` or `false`_)

Comment: Yes, even I don't get a||= b is a||a = b, can you explain? @potashin

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why this doesn't cover the question?
@Drenmi, added edit to clarify.

Comment: It is unlikely you will receive an explanation @varevarao, but with the added research effort, you have my upvote. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference becomes more obvious if you use a class with getter and setter:

```
class Foo
  def var
    puts 'Foo#var called'
    @var
  end
  def var=(value)
    puts 'Foo#var= called'
    @var = value
  end
end
```

Your first example results in `Foo#var=` being called very time:

```
f = Foo.new
f.var = f.var || "Default Value"
# Foo#var called
# Foo#var= called
f.var = f.var || "Default Value"
# Foo#var called
# Foo#var= called
```

Whereas in your second example, `Foo#var=` is only called once:

```
f = Foo.new
f.var ||= "Default Value"
# Foo#var called
# Foo#var= called
f.var ||= "Default Value"
# Foo#var called
```

Comment: Why `Foo.var` was not called second time in second case?

Comment: @WandMaker `||=` makes an assignment only if the left hand value was `nil` or `false`. `f.var` is initially `nil`, so the first `f.var ||=` assigns `"Default value"`. The second time, `f.var` returns `"Default value"`, so no assignment is performed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an equivalent expression would be something like `f.var.tap { |v| f.var = v || 'Default value' unless v }`